# How do I set a mock date in Jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, momentjs

I'm using moment.js to do most of my date logic in a helper file for my React components but I haven't been able to figure out how to mock a date in Jest a la `sinon.useFakeTimers()`.

The Jest docs only speak about timer functions like `setTimeout`, `setInterval` etc but don't help with setting a date and then checking that my date functions do what they're meant to do.

Here is some of my JS file:

```js
var moment = require('moment');

var DateHelper = {
  
  DATE_FORMAT: 'MMMM D',
  API_DATE_FORMAT: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
  
  formatDate: function(date) {
    return date.format(this.DATE_FORMAT);
  },

  isDateToday: function(date) {
    return this.formatDate(date) === this.formatDate(moment());
  }
};


module.exports = DateHelper;
```

and here is what I've set up using Jest:

```js
jest.dontMock('../../../dashboard/calendar/date-helper')
    .dontMock('moment');

describe('DateHelper', function() {
  var DateHelper = require('../../../dashboard/calendar/date-helper'),
      moment = require('moment'),
      DATE_FORMAT = 'MMMM D';

  describe('formatDate', function() {

    it('should return the date formatted as DATE_FORMAT', function() {
      var unformattedDate = moment('2014-05-12T00:00:00.000Z'),
          formattedDate = DateHelper.formatDate(unformattedDate);

      expect(formattedDate).toEqual('May 12');
    });

  });

  describe('isDateToday', function() {

    it('should return true if the passed in date is today', function() {
      var today = moment();

      expect(DateHelper.isDateToday(today)).toEqual(true);
    });
    
  });

});
```

Now these tests pass because I'm using moment and my functions use moment but it seems a bit unstable and I would like to set the date to a fixed time for the tests.

Any idea on how that could be accomplished?

Comment: can you please select a different answer, since jest now has inbuilt date mocking?

Answer (score 460, accepted):

As of Jest 26 this can be achieved using "modern" fake timers without needing to install any 3rd party modules: https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26#new-fake-timers

```js
jest
  .useFakeTimers()
  .setSystemTime(new Date('2020-01-01'));
```

If you want the fake timers to be active for *all* tests, you can set `timers: 'modern'` in your configuration: https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#timers-string

EDIT: As of Jest 27 modern fake timers is the default, so you can drop the argument to `useFakeTimers`.

Comment: Also worth noting, the `.useFakeTimers('modern')` bit can be called from a global config file (like `setupTests.js`). So that in can be easily removed once that's the default option. From that same link: `In Jest 27 we will swap the default to the new "modern"`.

Comment: You may want to [`jest.useRealTimers()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestuserealtimers) after you  are done  with the  fake-timers.

Comment: This solution is only working for me only if I call `jest.setSystemTime()` in the test setup; if I call it in `beforeAll` of my test suite, it is ignored. Check the repo I created for testing this https://github.com/dariospadoni/jestFakeTimersMock/blob/main/src/setupTests.js

Comment: This is the most clean solution. BTW, you can also give a Date object to setSystemTime, no need to convert to epoch time.

Comment: As of Jest 27, you get this error `TypeError: setSystemTime is not available when not using modern timers`. Just remove `.setSystemTime(...)`.

Comment: jest 26: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. for useFakeTimers('modern')

Comment: this is good, this worked for me instead of useFakeTimers({now: new Date(xxxx)})

Comment: Make sure you call this before rendering / mounting your component! :)

Comment: Weirdly, removing useFakeTimers did not work for me (jest@29.5.0):
```
jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2021-08-16T12:00:00.000Z')); // worked
jest.setSystemTime(new Date('2021-08-16T12:00:00.000Z')); // dates generated via 'getTime' will be the real date
```

Comment: I also needed to leave the `useFakeTimers` call in to get this to work with jest 29.7.0

Answer (score 228):

Since momentjs uses `Date` internally, you can just overwrite the `Date.now` function to always return the same moment.

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => 1487076708000) //14.02.2017
```

or

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 1, 14)).valueOf())
```

Comment: Here's a little bit prettier method of setting the actual date that will be returned: `Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 0, 1)).valueOf());`

Comment: Or even a little bit prettier:`Date.now = jest.fn(() => +new Date('2017-01-01');`

Comment: OR: `Date.now = jest.fn(() => Date.parse('2017-02-14))`

Comment: Will this properly mock all uses of `Date`? Like `new Date()`?

Comment: @EliasZamaria no. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377110/2334415) does cover that use case though.

Comment: What about reverting it? So other tests can use `Date.now()`

Comment: @JeremyEaton missing a `'`

Answer (score 161):

For a robust solution, look at [timekeeper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timekeeper):

```
import timekeeper from 'timekeeper';

beforeAll(() => {
    // Lock Time
    timekeeper.freeze(new Date('2014-01-01'));
});

afterAll(() => {
    // Unlock Time
    timekeeper.reset();
});
```

**For older versions of Jest:**

For quick and dirty solution use [jest.spyOn](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestspyonobject-methodname) for locking time:

```
let dateNowSpy;

beforeAll(() => {
    // Lock Time
    dateNowSpy = jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(() => 1487076708000);
});

afterAll(() => {
    // Unlock Time
    dateNowSpy.mockRestore();
});
```

Comment: Great solution; no dependencies and keeping it resettable makes it easy to apply to a single test.

Comment: No need for `dateNowSpy` variable, and the `mockReset()` is redundant according to https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api.html#mockfnmockrestore.

In the `afterAll`, you can simply do `Date.now.mockRestore()`

Comment: this is great so then you don't need any additional libraries. But this will only really work if you're using static Date methods (which aren't many)

Comment: @Jimmy `Date.now.mockRestore();` gives a _Property 'mockRestore' does not exist on type '() => number'_ error

Comment: @Marco it should be jest.spyOn(Date, "now").mockRestore();

Comment: I reckon it's more straightforward to use a variable for a spy. To make typescript happy use `let dateNowSpy: jest.SpyInstance;`.

Comment: Useful and modern

Comment: should be import * as timekeeper from 'timekeeper'; or  var timekeeper = require('timekeeper'); in 2023.

Answer (score 108):

[MockDate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockdate) can be used in jest tests to change what `new Date()` returns:

```
var MockDate = require('mockdate');
// I use a timestamp to make sure the date stays fixed to the ms
MockDate.set(1434319925275);
// test code here
// reset to native Date()
MockDate.reset();
```

Comment: Worked great because I was using other functions of `Date` like `valueOf()`.

Comment: Same i needed to mock the date, but also have `Date.parse` available and this works perfectly! I did this previously: ```dateSpy = jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => new Date('1990-03-30T09:00:00'));``` but it stops the static methods on `Date` from working.

Answer (score 45):

For those who want to mock methods on a `new Date` object you can do the following:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getDay').mockReturnValue(2);
    jest.spyOn(Date.prototype, 'toISOString').mockReturnValue('2000-01-01T00:00:00.000Z');
});

afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
});
```

Comment: This worked well for me, nice, simple and clean. Good suggestion!

Comment: What I like about this method is that it can be extended to mock any part of the `Date` prototype that you need to control as part of your tests. Plus it only relies on `Jest` for this feature, which is nice to keep the dependencies down.

Comment: Short and simple, this worked for me.

Answer (score 10):

This works for me:

```js
const mockDate = new Date('14 Oct 1995')
global.Date = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => mockDate) // mock Date "new" constructor
global.Date.now = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(mockDate.valueOf()) // mock Date.now
```

Comment: it is fine, but not suitable for Typescript without applying @ts-ignore

Comment: I'm using NestJS, the code above works fine for me, no @ts-ignore needed

Comment: this worked for me, I was trying to mock "new Date()", thanks.

Comment: This worked for me and I'm using Typescript version 5.3.3 with Node 16

Answer (score 9):

Here are a few readable ways for different use cases. I prefer using spies over saving references to the original objects, which can be accidentally overwritten in some other code.

### One-off mocking

```js
jest
  .spyOn(global.Date, 'now')
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => Date.parse('2020-02-14'));
```

### A few tests

```js
let dateSpy;

beforeAll(() => {
  dateSpy = jest
    .spyOn(global.Date, 'now')
    .mockImplementation(() => Date.parse('2020-02-14'));
});

afterAll(() => {
  dateSpy.mockRestore();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

All the answer based only on the mock of `Date.now()` will not work everywhere since some packages (for instance `moment.js`) use `new Date()` instead.

In this context the answer based on `MockDate` is I think the only truly correct. If you don't want to use an external package, you can write directly in your `beforeAll`:

```
  const DATE_TO_USE = new Date('2017-02-02T12:54:59.218Z');
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
  const _Date = Date;
  const MockDate = (...args) => {
    switch (args.length) {
      case 0:
        return DATE_TO_USE;
      default:
        return new _Date(...args);
    }
  };
  MockDate.UTC = _Date.UTC;
  MockDate.now = () => DATE_TO_USE.getTime();
  MockDate.parse = _Date.parse;
  MockDate.toString = _Date.toString;
  MockDate.prototype = _Date.prototype;
  global.Date = MockDate;
```

Answer (score 8):

[jest-date-mock](https://github.com/hustcc/jest-date-mock) is a complete javascript module wrote by me, and it is used to test Date on jest.

```
import { advanceBy, advanceTo } from 'jest-date-mock';

test('usage', () => {
  advanceTo(new Date(2018, 5, 27, 0, 0, 0)); // reset to date time.

  const now = Date.now();

  advanceBy(3000); // advance time 3 seconds
  expect(+new Date() - now).toBe(3000);

  advanceBy(-1000); // advance time -1 second
  expect(+new Date() - now).toBe(2000);

  clear();
  Date.now(); // will got current timestamp
});
```

Use the only 3 api for test cases.

- advanceBy(ms): advance date timestamp by ms.
- advanceTo([timestamp]): reset date to timestamp, default to 0.
- clear(): shut down the mock system.

Comment: what is your case?

Answer (score 6):

Since `Jest` version `29` you can do the following as well:

```js
jest.useFakeTimers({
  now: 1673445238335,
});
```

The following options are allowed:

```js
type FakeTimersConfig = {
  /**
   * If set to `true` all timers will be advanced automatically by 20 milliseconds
   * every 20 milliseconds. A custom time delta may be provided by passing a number.
   * The default is `false`.
   */
  advanceTimers?: boolean | number;
  /**
   * List of names of APIs that should not be faked. The default is `[]`, meaning
   * all APIs are faked.
   */
  doNotFake?: Array<FakeableAPI>;
  /**
   * Use the old fake timers implementation instead of one backed by `@sinonjs/fake-timers`.
   * The default is `false`.
   */
  legacyFakeTimers?: boolean;
  /** Sets current system time to be used by fake timers. The default is `Date.now()`. */
  now?: number | Date;
  /**
   * The maximum number of recursive timers that will be run when calling `jest.runAllTimers()`.
   * The default is `100_000` timers.
   */
  timerLimit?: number;
};
```

You can read more in the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestusefaketimersfaketimersconfig).

Answer (score 5):

This is how I mocked my `Date.now()` method to set the year to 2010 for my test

```
jest
  .spyOn(global.Date, 'now')
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => new Date(`2010`).valueOf());
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach. I kind of combined a couple answers and put this at the top of one of my test files: `jest.spyOn(global.Date, 'now').mockImplementation(() => 1487076708000);`

Answer (score 4):

To mock `toISOString` you can do:

```js
jest.spyOn(global.Date.prototype, 'toISOString').mockReturnValue('2023-09-06T11:54:47.050Z')
```

Comment: for some reason I can't suggest a change, but your mock value isn't a real iso string, `"2023-09-06T11:54:47.050Z"` would be valid however

Comment: @HaroenViaene makes sense, amended that

Answer (score 3):

I'm using moment + moment-timezone and none of these worked for me.

This worked:

```
jest.mock('moment', () => {
  const moment = jest.requireActual('moment');
  moment.now = () => +new Date('2022-01-18T12:33:37.000Z');
  return moment;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to offer some alternative approaches.

If you need to stub `format()` (which can be locale and timezone dependent!)

```
import moment from "moment";
...
jest.mock("moment");
...
const format = jest.fn(() => 'April 11, 2019')
moment.mockReturnValue({ format })
```

If you only need to stub `moment()`:

```
import moment from "moment";
...
jest.mock("moment");
...
const now = "moment(\"2019-04-11T09:44:57.299\")";
moment.mockReturnValue(now);
```

Regarding the test for the `isDateToday` function above, I believe the simplest way would be not to mock `moment` at all

Comment: For the first example, I get ```TypeError: moment.mockReturnValue is not a function```

Comment: Is `jest.mock("moment")` at the same level as your import statements? Otherwise, you are welcome to see it in action in [this project](https://github.com/DeveloperDavo/my-notes)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like use Manual Mocks, so it can use in all tests.

```js
// <rootDir>/__mocks__/moment.js
const moment = jest.requireActual('moment')

Date.now = jest.fn(() => 1558281600000) // 2019-05-20 00:00:00.000+08:00

module.exports = moment
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to mock the whole Date and 'now' function before test:

`const mockedData = new Date('2020-11-26T00:00:00.000Z');`

`jest.spyOn(global, 'Date').mockImplementation(() => mockedData);`

`Date.now = () => 1606348800;`

`describe('test', () => {...})`

Answer (score 1):

Improving a bit the @pranava-s-balugari response

1. It does noe affect `new Date(something)`
2. The mocked date can be changed.
3. It will work fot Date.now too

```js
const DateOriginal = global.Date;

global.Date = class extends DateOriginal {
    constructor(params) {
        if (params) {
          super(params)
        } else if (global.Date.NOW === undefined) {
          super()
        } else {
          super(global.Date.NOW)
        }
    }
    static now () {
      return new Date().getTime();
    }
}

afterEach(() => {
  global.Date.NOW = undefined;
})

afterAll(() => {
  global.Date = DateOriginal;
});

describe('some test', () => {
  afterEach(() => NOW = undefined);

  it('some test', () => {
     Date.NOW = '1999-12-31T23:59:59' // or whatever parameter you could pass to new Date([param]) to get the date you want


     expect(new Date()).toEqual(new Date('1999-12-31T23:59:59'));
     expect(new Date('2000-01-01')).toEqual(new Date('2000-01-01'));
     expect(Date.now()).toBe(946681199000)

     Date.NOW = '2020-01-01'

     expect(new Date()).toEqual(new Date('2020-01-01'));
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works good -

```
Date.now = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(new Date('2021-08-29T18:16:19+00:00'));
```

But if we want to run unit tests in pipeline we have to make sure we are using the same time zone. To do that we have to mock timezone as well -

jest.config.js

```js
process.env.TZ = 'GMT';

module.exports = {
 ...
};
```

See also: [the full list of timezones (column TZ database name)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Answer (score 1):

I was using an external library and to make it work I had to run this code on the setup stage:

```
Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date(Date.UTC(2021, 2, 30)).valueOf());
```

I wrote this in my `setupTests.ts` file set in the `setupFilesAfterEnv` prop from `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'],
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into issues with most implementations.

While `jest.setSystemTime(new Date(date));` is attractive, in practice, it was not overriding the date in many circumstances.

Just overriding `Date.now` is OK, but I also use `new Date` throughout the codebase, as does `moment`.

Finally, I felt that a package was simply overkill.

After much trial and error, taking some inspiration from the answers here, here is my solution, which inherits from Date, so it will have all it's properties, and will account for different types of parameters (such as multiple parameters, without which `moment().startOf('day')` wasn't working).

```
// default mock date, if you want one
export const setDateToReturnMockDate = (date) => {
  const mockDate = new Date(date);
  const _Date = Date;
  class MockDate extends _Date {
    // can accept an array, e.g. new Date(2023, 3, 2);
    constructor(...date) {
      return date.length ? new _Date(...date) : mockDate;
    }
  }
  MockDate.now = () => +mockDate;
  global.Date = MockDate;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, using just

```js
jest.useFakeTimers({
  now: 1673445238335,
});
```

leads to freezes in async/await functions. To avoid freezes, I don't mock some APIs:

```
      jest.useFakeTimers({
        doNotFake: [
          "setImmediate",
          "clearImmediate",
          "setTimeout",
          "clearTimeout",
          "setInterval",
          "clearInterval",
          "nextTick",
          "queueMicrotask",
        ],
        now: new Date(TEST_DATE),
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Goal is to mock new Date() with a fixed date wherever it's used during the component rendering for test purposes. Using libraries will be an overhead if the only thing you want is to mock new Date() fn.

Idea is to store the global date to a temp variable, mock the global date and then after usage reassign temp to global date.

```js
export const stubbifyDate = (mockedDate: Date) => {
    /**
     * Set Date to a new Variable
     */
    const MockedRealDate = global.Date;

    /**
     *  Mock Real date with the date passed from the test
     */
    (global.Date as any) = class extends MockedRealDate {
        constructor() {
            super()
            return new MockedRealDate(mockedDate)
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reset global.Date to original Date (MockedRealDate) after every test
     */
    afterEach(() => {
        global.Date = MockedRealDate
    })
}

Usage in your test would be like

import { stubbyifyDate } from './AboveMethodImplementedFile'

describe('<YourComponent />', () => {
    it('renders and matches snapshot', () => {
        const date = new Date('2019-02-18')
        stubbifyDate(date)

        const component = renderer.create(
            <YourComponent data={}/>
        );
        const tree = component.toJSON();
        expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});
```

Comment: Explain your Answer as well. putting code only is not the good approach

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Updated with comments.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to chime in here since no answer addressed the issue if you want to mock the `Date` object in only a specific suite.

You can mock it using the setup and teardown methods for each suite, [jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/setup-teardown)

```js
/**
 * Mocking Date for this test suite
 */
const globalDate = Date;

beforeAll(() => {
  // Mocked Date: 2020-01-08
  Date.now = jest.fn(() => new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 8)).valueOf());
});

afterAll(() => {
  global.Date = globalDate;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: OMG why does Date.UTC use 0 based months?

I thought I was going crazy, by being a month off the whole time.


    new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 0, 8)).valueOf() --> January 8th 2020

    new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 1, 8)).valueOf() --> February 8th 2020 

and then only for months, not days or years

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date-faker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-faker). Lets you change the current date relatively:

```
import { dateFaker } from 'date-faker';
// or require if you wish: var { dateFaker } = require('date-faker');

// make current date to be tomorrow
dateFaker.add(1, 'day'); // 'year' | 'month' | 'day' | 'hour' | 'minute' | 'second' | 'millisecond'.

// change using many units
dateFaker.add({ year: 1, month: -2, day: 3 });

// set specific date, type: Date or string
dateFaker.set('2019/01/24');

// reset
dateFaker.reset();
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way I have found is just to override the prototype with whatever function you are using.

```
Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset = function () {
   return 456;
};

Date.prototype.getTime = function () {
      return 123456;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The following test stubs Date to return a constant during the test lifecycle.

If you have use `new Date()` in your project then you could mock it in your test file something like this:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    let time_now = Date.now();
    const _GLOBAL: any = global;
    _GLOBAL.Date = class {
      public static now() {
        return time_now;
      }
    };
}
```

Now wherever you will use `new Date()` in your test file, It will produce the same timestamp.

Note: you could replace `beforeEach` with `beforeAll`. And `_GLOBAL` is just a proxy variable to satisfy typescript.

The complete code I tried:

```
let time_now;
const realDate = Date;

describe("Stubbed Date", () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    timeNow = Date.now();
    const _GLOBAL: any = global;
    _GLOBAL.Date = class {
      public static now() {
        return time_now;
      }

      constructor() {
        return time_now;
      }

      public valueOf() {
        return time_now;
      }
    };
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    global.Date = realDate;
  });

  it("should give same timestamp", () => {
    const date1 = Date.now();
    const date2 = new Date();
    expect(date1).toEqual(date2);
    expect(date2).toEqual(time_now);
  });
});
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [`sinonjs/fake-timers`](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers). It's very similar to the fake timer provided by `jest`, but much more user-friendly.

```js
import FakeTimers from '@sinonjs/fake-timers';

const clock = FakeTimers.install()
clock.setSystemTime(new Date('2022-01-01'));

console.log(new Date()) // 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.useFakeTimers('modern').setSystemTime(new Date('2023-03-01'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jest.useFakeTimers({ now: Number(new Date()) })
```

Jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks

Answer (score 0):

Using Jest fake timers may add additional complexity when working with async code: `jest.useFakeTimers` overrides the global `setTimeout` which is used in RTL `waitFor`, `waitForNextUpdate` and similar. Adding a jest spy could solve this:

```
import jest from 'jest';

jest.spyOn(Date, 'now');

const now = Date.now(); // mocked `Date.now() value
```

If you want to use a specific mocked date:

```
const mockDateNow = 1689975660000
jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockReturnedValue(mockDateNow);
```