# How can I make this line work in jest ? => jasmine.clock().install();

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I have a unit test that use jasmin.clock.install

I have the following error using [jest-cli 20.0.4](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/v20.0.4)

```
TypeError: jasmine.clock is not a function
```

What package should I have in order to have this line work in my unit test :

```
jasmine.clock().install();
```

I managed to make it work by downgrading to jest-cli 19.0.1. it would be nice to know the upgrade procedure.

Comment: What are you trying to archive, maybe there is an equivalent for this in Jest

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719631/how-do-i-set-a-mock-date-in-jest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs `jasmine.clock().install();` is needed to mock out `setTimeout` calls. So this can be done in Jest by using `jest.useFakeTimers();`. Have a look at the [docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/timer-mocks.html#content) on how to mock timer in Jest. Also have a look at the [announcement](http://facebook.github.io/jest/blog/2017/05/06/jest-20-delightful-testing-multi-project-runner.html#breaking-changes) of `v20` to see why the Jasmine stuff does not work anymore