# Jest testing function that involves current date

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a function that check whether the param is the same with or later than today, in my function I used new Date() like so

```
import moment from "moment";

const validateDate = ({ date }) => {
  return moment(date, "DD-MM-YYYY").isSameOrAfter(
    moment(new Date(), "DD-MM-YYYY", "days")
  );
};

export default validateDate;
```

My test will be like so:

```
import validateDate from "./index";

it("is same or after today", () => {
  expect(validateDate({ date: "16-05-2019" })).toBeTruthy();
});
```

The problem is that the test will fail on 17-05-2019. How to solve this issue?

I tried this idea but not sure whether it's fine or not.

```
const validateDate = ({ date, today = new Date() }) => {
      return moment(date, "DD-MM-YYYY").isSameOrAfter(
        moment(today, "DD-MM-YYYY", "days")
      );
    };
```

My test:

```
expect(validateDate({ date: "16-05-2019" }, today: new Date())).toBeTruthy();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a mock date in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719631/how-do-i-set-a-mock-date-in-jest)

Comment: @imjared I didn't pass in the value into the function

Answer (score 3):

You can mock `Date` object to sure that `new Date()` returns a condition date.

```
global.Date = class extends RealDate {
  constructor() {
    super();
    return new RealDate(isoDate);
  }
};
```

Just overwrite global Date object before a test, then restore after you finish the test.

Final code:

```
describe("validateDate", () => {
  const RealDate = Date;

  function mockDate(isoDate) {
    global.Date = class extends RealDate {
      constructor() {
        super();
        return new RealDate(isoDate);
      }
    } as any;
  }

  afterEach(() => {
    global.Date = RealDate;
  });

  it("should return true", () => {
    mockDate(moment("15-05-2019", "DD-MM-YYYY").toISOString());
    expect(validateDate({date: "16-05-2019", today: new Date()})).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to supply dynamic date for the test. For example, the first test will be given today as the date, while the second will be yesterday, with the following code: `moment().subtract(1, 'days').valueOf()`

More detailed example:

```js
desc("is same or after today", () => {
  it('should return true for today', () => {
    expect(validateDate({
      date: moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY').valueOf()
    })).toBeTruthy();
  })

  it('should return true for yesterday', () => {
    expect(validateDate({
      date: moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY').valueOf()
    })).toBeTruthy();
  })
});
```

Comment: can you write some codes? why is it my second approach is not proper?

Comment: I don't like your second approach since you need to change your code according to make the test work.