# Jest: setSystemTime is not available when not using modern timers

Tags: jestjs

Here is the code. I'm getting error `TypeError: setSystemTime is not available when not using modern timers` when I run the test. I have `"@jest/fake-timers": "^27.4.2"` in my package.json since I thought there could be a conflict on the package in some dependencies, but issue remains

```
beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers('modern');
    jest.setSystemTime(new Date());
});

afterAll(() => {
    jest.useRealTimers();
});
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

Facing the same issue here, [this patch from @stereodenis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42787232/1614677) is working (copying it here):

```js
let dateNowSpy: jest.SpyInstance;
const today = new Date('2000-01-01').getTime();

describe('...', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    dateNowSpy = jest.spyOn(Date, 'now').mockImplementation(() => today);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    dateNowSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  test('...', () => {
    /* Date.now() -> 2000-01-01 */
  });
```

Comment: Worked great! One change though, the first line needs an '=', not a ':'
let dateNowSpy = jest.SpyInstance;

Comment: @C.T.Bell I don't think that's correct, the code above is valid, it's declaring a variable of type `jest.SpyInstance` with an undefined value

Comment: @C.T.Bell this is ts code, it's declaring the type of `dateNowSpy` in pure js just suppress this declaration (-> `let dateNowSpy;`)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11660#issuecomment-879615014), it can be solved by checking the version of jest and it's related packages. For example, I had jest on version 26.6.0 and babel-jest and ts-jest on 27.x. Setting them to 26.x solved the problem.